# npm caching issue- did not rebuild

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, vue.js

I'm using Laravel 5.4 with vue.js . Then i had syntax error between created and methods. I forgot , then i fix this error.

But still the error continue.

```
<script>
export default {

    data(){
        return {
          users: []
        }

    },

    created(){
      this.fetchUsers();
    },//forgotten

    methods:{ //41.line
      fetchUsers(){
        this.$http.get('/users').then(response => {
          this.users = response.data.users;
        });
      }

    }

}
</script>
```

I was restarted apache.But still have this error if i write "npm run dev" or "npm run watch".

```
    error  in ./resources/assets/js/components/Users.vue

    Syntax Error: Unexpected token, expected , (41:4)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/.npm/_logs/2017-07-11T08_13_41_572Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/.npm/_logs/2017-07-11T08_13_41_618Z-debug.log
```

**EDIT**

I listen your advice and applied.I mean the problem is not relevant syntax mistake.The problem is old code execute insead of new code.I saved all file and then "npm run dev" but return same error everytime.

Comment: What node version are you using?

Comment: show your full component code - nevertheless, it seems like you are mixing two ecmascript styles

Comment: node version 8.1.3 @mscdex

Comment: the code added @FrankProvost

Comment: i tried this advice.Replace the methods.But everytime error on 41.line so absurd @MU

Comment: this was a really bad advice @MU it clearly states it's a sytnax error. Changing created to mounted will change the behaviour

Comment: remote the `:` behind methods - try methods { ... }

Comment: Use `fetchUsers: function () {}` instead of `fetchUsers(){}`

Comment: @HirenGohel no. Heh as to use what he has or arrow function as otherwise he will have issues with binding this

Comment: @MU Ok, my mistake!

Comment: @MU fetchUsers: function(){} is perfectly acceptable. An arrow function would *definitely* cause issues.

Comment: I listen your advice and applied.I mean the problem is not relevant syntax mistake.The problem is old code execute insead of new code.I saved all file and then "npm run dev" but return same error everytime.

Comment: I agree, there does not appear to be a code problem here. Some sort of caching issue.

Comment: so have you an advice? @BertEvans

Comment: Can you show the full error log and maybe your webpack config? Have you tried opening your file in a different editor to confirm its contents? Have you tried re-typing it out in case there is a problematic unicode character in there?

Answer (score 0):

Even I got the same `error- A` complete log of this run can be found in:
The problem is with the port number, go to `package.json` file and change the port number to anything you want, say `8000`. For example:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js --progress",
    "watch": "npm run build -- --watch",
    "server": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --port 8000 --content-base src",
    "start": "npm run server"
  }
```

Earlier the port number was `3000`, and on `npm start` different application use to render on port `3000` so for my new application I gave port number `8000`. Now I can have two different application on different ports (localhost:3000 and localhost:8000) without getting error.